# Graphite is summing data

Tags: java, grafana, metrics, graphite, codahale-metrics

I am using `com.codahale.metrics` to send my metrics to Graphite in hopes of then displaying said data in grafana.
One of the Metrics that I am reporting is a counter, that counts occurrences of an action. And if I look in graphite(via grafana) with the time interval set to 1 hour, then it works and I am getting the data that is reported.

Should be noted here that it reports the same value over and over again, but it is only the last data that is important anyways so it is fine that the last 60 points are the same.

However the issue is when I increase the time interval to 3 hours. It then returns the sum of a few datapoints. So in this case it returns 18 datapoints(shouldn't be fewer than with 1 hour interval) and all of the datapoints are around 10 times as high as they should be (because it is summed)

After reading a bit it looks like it is because the maxDataPoint is exceeded, but my cap is at 10000 and I have this line in my target `consolidateBy(action.count, 'last')`

So what is going on, and how do I prevent this from happening?

Comment: Can you post your grafana query? If you use the bare metric it should report the last data point.